# RESTful API: What to do when there is nothing to return

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

From what I understand about RESTful APIs:

- If I'm asking for an ID that doesn't exist (for example `/users/999/posts` where user 999 doesn't exist), it should return a `404` status code.
- If I'm asking for a list of object, using valid IDs, but there is nothing to return, it should return `200` status code with empty array (for example `/users/999/posts` where user 999 exists but never posted anything)

Questions I've seen here are usually about those two cases.

Now my question is about when I have no data, I'm using valid IDs, but I'm supposed to return an object instead of a list.

For example, let's assume that for some reason I don't want to always return the user's address when I ask for `/users/999`. I have this different route: `/users/999/address` which returns an address object.

What should be returned if that user doesn't have any address? An empty object `{}` ? `404` status code? `204` status code?

I would think an empty object to be consistent?

Googling, I found [this](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/announcements/show/rXIx7RPr)
saying:

> The call to return the leagues or teams for a given summoner ID will now return a 404 instead of an empty object. This behavior is the correct RESTful behavior when the requested resource (i.e., leagues or teams) doesn’t exist.

So I'm a bit confused as to what the proper RESTful behaviour should be.

Thanks!

Comment: If the address resource does not exist,  and the client asks for it (because of an erroneous knowledge on the resource state), the client is making a mistake, that's why the `404`

Comment: @IlioCatallo: But how is the client supposed to know this specific user has an address or not?

Comment: I would explicit the relationship by using a hypermedia control form the client resource to the address resource, as dictated by the HATEOAS constraint

Comment: I don't think there are any rules to strictly answer to your question, but personnaly I would return a 200 or 204 because the request is a success. The fact that the user doesn't have an address is another point, but shouldn't be a reason to return an http error status. Except maybe if the address is a non nullable field in your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `404` should result from requesting a non-existing address. Indeed, if the address resource does not exist, and the client asks for it (because of an erroneous knowledge on the resource state), the client is making a mistake.

Regarding your point about discovering that a given user has an associated address or not, I would explicit the relationship by using a hypermedia control form the client resource to the address resource, as dictated by the [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) constraint.

Moreover, the address resource is a weak entity w.r.t. the correspoding user. Hence, it is makes sense to return `404` for the two cases. You can still take advantage of the HTTP entity body to better explain what happened.

Comment: Why then should /users/999/posts return an empty array and not a 404 error too? It's this distinction I don't understand...

Comment: IMHO, if the user has  no posts – but the client still asks for them (because it erroneously thinks she has) – the server should return `404`. In general, I would take advantage of the uniform interface provided by HTTP as much as possible.

Comment: @IlioCatallo IMO that approach puts an additional burden on the consumer (and the API). They need to write code to check for 404 rather than iterating over an empty list; I'm not sure what benefit is gained from the 404.

I see the distinction is you're asking for a collection not a specific item in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it from the consumer's point of view, would they rather use the same code when there are no addresses, or have to write a special case for no addresses?

I return an empty collection because it's less work for consumers (and for the REST service, but that's a bonus).

If the request was `/users/999/addresses` and user `999` didn't exist I'd return a `404`.

EDIT: If /users/999/address is the canonical address for the resource (that is it's incorrect to say /users/999/address/1) then I'd return a 404 because the user requested a specific and precise thing.

Comment: I agree about lists, it's my second bullet point. I'm asking about when it's an object that is returned, not a collection

Comment: I've updated my answer. One thing I have discovered with REST is there is no One True Way. There are lots of different and vehemently argued opposing opinions. The best advice I've got is whatever you choose, make it consistent within your API.